# Python: convert TimeObject [0:00:07] into seconds

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a pandas object of time. How do I convert them into seconds. I have over 8 hours worth of data.

```
0    [0:00:03]
1    [0:00:03]
2    [0:00:03]
3    [0:00:04]
4    [0:00:04]
```

Comment: is that format Hours:Minutes:Seconds?

Comment: I can’t tell if those are strings, lists of strings, lists of timedelta objects, or something else. You’ll have to show us more. Read [mcve]

Comment: Yes it is. But brackets are making it harder for pandas to recognize it as a time object.

Comment: What type is the column?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a series of single-item lists, with each item a string:

```
s = pd.Series([['0:00:03'], ['0:00:03'], ['0:00:03'], ['0:00:04'], ['0:00:04']])

res = pd.to_timedelta(s.str[0]).dt.total_seconds()

print(res)

0    3.0
1    3.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    4.0
dtype: float64
```